# How to solve the error which occur during the installation of the reactjs in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu-18.04

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abdul/.npm/_logs/2020-04-18T10_19_43_524Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? You don't have access to write to `/usr/lib/node-modules`; you may want to rerun that command with `sudo` (though I'd discourage doing so).

Comment: Try ```sudo``` in front of the command you are trying to run..